# uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^{nx^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have found pointwise convergence in R-{0}.To study uniform convergence I calculate $f'_n(x)$ and I found a max in x=0 so Sup $f_n(x)$= Sup $\frac{n}{e^{nx^2}}=n$ in R-{0} and I can't use Weierstrass theorem.
So in which intervals can I study uniform convergence?

Comment: What is $f_n(x)$?

Comment: "in which intervals can I study uniform convergence?" exactly where you found pointwise convergence. Consider the interval $(0, \infty )$, ($(- \infty ,0)$ will be the same). You will see that convergence is not uniform.

Comment: It is uniform in $\{x: |x| \geq \epsilon\}$ and it is not uniform in intervals containing $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ x \geq 1$ we have that $e^{nx^2} \geq e^n$ hence $\frac{n}{e^{nx^2}} \leq \frac{n}{e^n}$ and series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n}$ converges by the ratio test.  So the convergence is uniform for $x \geq 1$.